# RSS Feed has older items at the top

Tags: rss

My site's RSS news feed has most of the items expected, but begins with two older items, both of which have pubDate tags with dates well before the rest of the items.

I looked at the revision history for the first post, and it doesn't appear to have been updated.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Are they sticky posts?

Comment: Why, yes, they are.

Comment: You could try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/ to have more control over your RSS feeds

Comment: @Nathan, if you post your response as an answer, I'll mark it correct. Amjad, I would vote you up, but I can't yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there are old items at the top of the RSS feed is because they are sticky posts.